# "org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it."

Tags: java

I'm getting "org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it." when I call a WS method with a Java client.
It crashes in WSSecurityUtil.class inside org.apache.wss4j.dom.util, in this section of code:

```
Node firstChild = parent.getFirstChild();
    if (firstChild == null) {
        return (Element)parent.appendChild(child);
    } else {
        return (Element)parent.insertBefore(child, firstChild);
    }
```

How can I fix this if the error seems (of course I'm not sure) to be in that package?
I will add client code if it's necessary.

Comment: I have conducted short investigation, and found that until this issue is closed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/WSS/issues/WSS-624 we need to add dependency on module: java.xml.ws